# OpenCV - Open an XML file from C++ to Python

Tags: python, c++, xml, opencv, opencv3.0

I'm working on a project to improve my skill in OpenCV and since I'm new, I lack a lot of knowledge. In my project, **I've detected faces on images, cropped the face area, converted it to grayscale, used LBPs and calculated the LBP image's histogram with** **calcHist**.

I've saved all these histograms using **FileStorage** as **.xlm** files. All of the above, **using C++ on Visual Studio**. Now I have some code with machine learning algorithms like SVM, Neural Network, knn etc. But all this code is in **Python 3**.

The next step I have in mind, is to take all these .xml files and **load them on a Python script, again using OpenCV** to use them, but I just can't manage to do it in the last couple of days.

The most simple thing I've tried to test it (from a post made July 2017):

```
import cv2

fs = cv2.FileStorage("aa048t2aaunaff001.png_olbp.xml", cv2.FILE_STORAGE_READ)

fn = fs.getNode("Camera_Matrix")
print (fn.mat())
```

Problems here:

**1. fs doesn't have a member "getNode". Did I do something wrong with an installation here?
 2. Printing outputs "None".**

XML file to load: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2TTkSDC13uQRk8tZlgxengzNW8

OpenCV: 3.3.0, Python: 3.6.2

Couldn't find anything else that worked, so I posted the simplest thing I've tried. Thanks for reading, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `help(fs)`. Looking at that, I'd say `fs['Camera_Matrix']` is what you want.

Comment: Seems to be working. "help(fs)" did help. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my post was answered about 3 months ago but no official answer was provided, I will answer my own question.

I successfully opened the file I wanted but I tried to access a matrix that didn't exist. I changed `fn = fs.getNode("Camera_Matrix")` to `fn = fs.getNode("my_histrogram")` and OpenCV successfully loaded the histogram.